# Big O running time of this algorithm

Tags: time-complexity, big-o

I'm finding it difficult to analyze time complexity of algorithms. Take as an example this algorithm, how do i find the running time in O notation?

```
loop(n)  
i = 1  
while i ≤ n  
    j = 1  
    while j ≤ i  
        j = 2 ∗ j  
    i = i + 1
```

Answer (score 1):

When given code like this, it often helps to work from the inside out. Your inner loop is given here:

```
j = 1
While j <= i 
    j = 2 * j
```

This loop works by repeatedly doubling j until it's greater than i. The number of times you can double 1 before you exceed i is Θ(log i), so each time the inner loop is run it does Θ(log i) work.

The outer loop counts up from 1 to n, so the work done is

> log 1 + log 2 + ... + log n
>
> = log (1 * 2 * ... * n) (using properties of logarithms).
>
> = log (n!)
>
> = Θ(n log n).

That last step follows from [Stirling's approximation](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling%27s_approximation).

So overall, the time complexity is Θ(n log n).

Answer (score 0):

From your post I understood, that you know about the meaning of the O notation, but have some issues with applying it. Here in this simple example it is sufficient to determine how many times (dependent on your input size) the loops are executed. To obtain the final value, you have to combine it.

First step: analyze the times of executions per loop. (non-loop or recursive statements have O(1).)

```
while(i<=n) 
... 
i=i+1
```

is executed n times, thus O(n)

The inner loop 
   while(j<=i)
      j=j*2

is executed i/2 times but i limited by n from the outer loop. So this is O(n).

As there is an inner loop in with O(n) in an outer loop you have to multiply the asymptitics, i.e., n*n  => O(n^2)

Comment: Your analysis of the inner loop, while technically correct, is not a tight bound and so your overall answer is not a tight bound.

Comment: actually this example was from an old exam where the supposedly correct answer is O(n*log(n))